# Angular ngFor: access items when using SlicePipe

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, slice, ngfor

I want to use the last `n` elements of `orbit` array, which does work using `| slice: -n`. Problem is, for every iteration I need to access not only the resp. item but also its successor. `orbit[i+1]` does not work as `orbit` is the original unsliced array.

Is there a way to access the (sliced) items `ngFor` is actually iterating over?, something like `collection` in

```js
orbit.slice(-5).map((position, i, collection) => {
    position;                // the item
    collection[i+1];         // item's successor
})
```

Here is my template:

```html
<g *ngFor="let position of orbit | slice: -5; index as i">
    <circle [attr.cx]="position.x" [attr.cy]="position.y" r=".2"></circle>
    <line *ngIf="orbit[i+1]" [attr.x1]="position.x" [attr.y1]="position.y" [attr.x2]="orbit[i+1].x"
        [attr.y2]="orbit[i+1].y">
    </line>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the code from your example?

In your TS file:

```
public get slicedOrbit() {
    return orbit.slice(-5).map((position, i, collection) => ({
        position,
        next: collection[i+1]
    }));
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<g *ngFor="let orbit of slicedOrbit">
    <circle [attr.cx]="orbit.position.x" [attr.cy]="orbit.position.y" r=".2"></circle>
    <line *ngIf="orbit.next" [attr.x1]="orbit.position.x" [attr.y1]="orbit.position.y" [attr.x2]="orbit.next.x"
        [attr.y2]="orbit.next.y">
    </line>
</g>
```

(The naming may not make a lot of sense but you get the idea)

Comment: Well of course, but I was hoping it could be done more easily...